# UIButton with background image: title text randomly does not appear

Tags: uibutton, uikit

I am setting the background image on a UIButton which has title text. This works fine, except that about 5% of the time, rarely and non-deterministically, with the same code, the text does not appear.

In my UIButton subclass:

```
[self setBackgroundImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Also set a background image for all other states.
```

In a UIButton category, I have this convenience method for setting the title:

```
- (void)setNormalTitle:(NSString *)title {
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
}
```

I'm not finding this issue having been encountered by anyone. Any ideas? I can always create a custom UIView which contains the button and draws text on top using a UILabel, but I wonder if there's a known issue I'm encountering here.

**Update**: I seem to have worked around the issue by setting the title asynchronously:

```
_tabCell = loadTopNibObject(@"MYTabSmall3HeaderCell");
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    _tabCell.tab0Button.normalTitle = @"Option 1";
    _tabCell.tab1Button.normalTitle = @"Option 2";
    _tabCell.tab2Button.normalTitle = @"Option 3";
});
```

**Update 2**: Nope, the above doesn't work. I've breakpointed and printed out the empty button's text, which reports the correct string even though the button appears blank. I've also tried running `setNeedsDisplay:` when the button is touched, to no avail. Also tried re-setting the button text to some specific string (e.g. `@"test"`) on touch but this doesn't kick in any visible letting.

Comment: Are you sure that whatever "title" you are passing into setNormalTitle is never nil or empty???  I would NSLog the title when it comes in...

Comment: Logged and added some asserts to make sure the title is never nil or an empty string, and I'm getting the same result. In fact I tried hardcoding the title value in the above to be a specific string, and the problem still happens.